# How do I use Cython for external module compilation, from within my setup.py file?

Tags: python, compilation, installation, cython, setup.py

First, if i have a project that is all python (no C++ or C) files, what is the advantage of using Cython, vs, say, using the python library directly (for integration in a large C++ software program) ?

Second, to compile the .pyx files to Cython, i intend to use `setup.py` file with this code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(MyString)
)
```

What should `MyString` be ? the name of the python (.pyx) files without extension ? should it include a full path ? where should be located the `setup.py` file so that it cythonizes the files ? If not this way, how to properly Cythonize the files ?

- **What is the proper way to use Cython when dealing with a library containing only .py files ?**
- **How to use the `setup.py` to cythonize (see more detailled questions above) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum there is a lot of question here.

1. what is the advantage of using Cython, vs, say, using the python library directly ?

   If you only use Python library (eg: for network stuff), using Cython should not be of great help. Cython will greatly help you if:

   - you need access to external C/C++ library;
   - or you need to build your own fast data structure possibly using C/C++ allocation;
   - or you have an intensive number crunching application.
2. What should MyString be ?

   They are a lot of option here. I usually use

   ```
   setup(
       cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
       ext_modules = [Extension("myext", ["myext.pyx", "myextlib.pyx"])])
   ```

   You'll find a lot of information at [Cython compilation documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html)
   For a small library, you can put it in the same directory as the source.

Answer (score 0):

[pypy](/questions/tagged/pypy) might give you better performance gains more quickly.

Comment: alternative is btw cythonizing the lib, or using the python lib with licence check elsewhere in the code. not pypy.